# Problema con flextable, Word y Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

estoy desarrollando una aplicación en shiny que tiene por objetivo automatizar la redacción de informes dentro de la empresa en qué trabajo. Estuve trabajando a través de Rcloud durante varios meses, sin mayores problemas además de el uso de memoria ram del servidor, sin embargo, ahora que estoy ocupando un equipo para correr la aplicación, ocurre que las tablas hechas con el paquete flextable contienen un error y este consiste en que las celdas de cada tabla no se ajustan al texto si no que siempre mantienen la misma altura, adjunto imagen y código utilizado. Dejo especificado que dicho error no ocurría en Rcloud e intuyo que puede deberse a la versión de Word, pero aún así, si es posible solucionar esto para todas las versiones de word, sería fantástico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(flextable)
library(officer)
library(janitor)

def_cell <- fp_cell(border = fp_border(color="#0068B3")) #color de los bordes de celda
def_par <- fp_par(text.align = "center") #alineado del texto
def_text <- fp_text(font.family = "Calibri") #tipo de letra
def_text_header <- update(def_text, bold = TRUE) #especificaciones del encabezado 

#(...)

cat_o %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  format(decimal.mark=",", big.mark = ".") %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  style(pr_c = def_cell, pr_p = def_par, pr_t = def_text, part = "all")  %>% 
   style(pr_t = def_text_header, part = "header") %>%
  bold(i=nrow(cat_o)) %>%  
  bg(bg = "#BFBFBF", part = "header") %>%
  width(width=6.5315/ncol(tab1)) %>% 
  add_footer_lines( "Fuente: Encuesta 2017") %>% 
  fontsize(size = 9, part = "footer") %>% 
  font(fontname = "Calibri",part = "footer") %>% 
  style(pr_p = def_par, part = "footer") %>% 
  add_header_lines("Tabla #: Categoría ocupacional") %>% 
  fontsize(size = 10, part = "footer") %>% 
  font(fontname = "Calibri",part = "footer") %>% 
  style(pr_p = def_par, part = "header",pr_t = def_text_header)

#(...)
```

Comment: Prueba usar el parámetro `padding` en `fp_par()` con algún valor superior a 0, eso debería agregar un espacio blanco alrededor de párrafo, mi hipótesis es que eso tal vez te asegure el ajuste de la celda.

Comment: Probé usando un valor `padding` igual a 5 pero sigue sin funcionar.
En cualquier caso, gracias por su sugerencia.